# Why aren't my quiver arrows pointing the correct direction?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am struggling to understand why my quiver arrows aren't pointing in the proper direction when plotting wind direction. I have provided an MWE below that has arrays dates, wind_dir, and wind_speed and plots their values over time. I use angles parameter as 'xy' so that arrows point from (x,y) to (x+u,y+v). Anyone have a minute to help?

```
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, YearLocator, MonthLocator, DayLocator, HourLo
#from file.py import *

dates = [datetime(2020, 4, 22, 0, 53),
datetime(2020, 4, 22, 1, 53),
datetime(2020, 4, 22, 2, 53),
datetime(2020, 4, 22, 3, 53)]

idx = date2num(dates)

wind_dir = [170., 150., 130., 230.]

wind_speed = [3.6,  2.57, 4.12, 7.09 ]

U = wind_speed*np.cos(wind_dir)
V = wind_speed*np.sin(wind_dir)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

qq = ax1.quiver(idx, np.ones(len(idx))*1,U,V,wind_speed,
   pivot='mid',angles='xy',cmap=plt.cm.jet)

plt.colorbar(qq, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
ax1.plot(dates, wind_speed)

# format the x ticks
months = MonthLocator()
days = DayLocator()
hours = HourLocator(byhour=[0,1,2,3])
hours_each = HourLocator() # Find all hours
dateFmt = DateFormatter('%b %d\n%H:%M') # Tick label format style
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dateFmt) # Set the x-axis labels
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hours_each)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `np.cos` and `np.sin` expect values in radians, not degrees.

Comment: Try `np.deg2rad`.